# How to show alert message based on server response in JSF

Tags: jsf

I have the following link in one of my JSPs. When an user clicks on that link I'm calling an action in my backing bean. I need to show a JavaScript alert message based on the response of that action.

```
<h:commandLink onclick="setSelectedClientAndFund();" id="next"
  action="#{fyeSelection.getFYEReportHome}">
    <h:graphicImage value="../images/NextBT.png"></h:graphicImage>
    <a4j:loadScript src="alert('hello');"></a4j:loadScript>
</h:commandLink>
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Just render the script conditionally:

```html
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{bean.show}">
    <script>alert('hello');</script>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Or when you're on JSF2 already:

```
<h:outputScript rendered="#{bean.show}">
    alert('hello');
</h:outputScript>
```

Comment: Hi thx for help now i'm able to show the script message but the script message is coming at the time of page initial load i want show it once completion of page load
   the script message should be conformation message if user clicks again "yes" i need to call another bean action how can i achieve this
      Please help in this

Comment: Just control the `rendered` outcome accordingly.

Comment: When `rendered="false"` the script won't be printed (and thus won't be executed). When `rendered="true"` then the script will be printed and executed. You need to ensure that `bean.isShow()` returns false during page initial load.